# Scaling multiple kubernetes node pools on azure

Tags: azure, powershell, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am in the middle of creating a function to schedule node pool scaling on azure.

This was fairly easy using the AKS Module and creating a function to scale the nodepool, but now the development team has started using multuple node pools in the same kubernetes service, usually i would just use the Set-AzAks as follow

```bsh
Set-AzAks -Name <name> -ResourceGroupName <rgname> -NodeCount 1
```

But i seem unable to specify individual node pools in the command. I have been able to use the az CLI tool to get the functionality i want doing it manually, but I really want to use the azure automation account to do this.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8934) which already existed in the Github. So I think it's not a good way to use the PowerShell command `Set-AzAks` to scale the AKS nodes count in the current situation.

For this, I recommend you to use the Azure REST API [Managed Clusters - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/createorupdate) through PowerShell, it will also work perfectly as the Azure CLI commands for you.

**Update:**

As you wish, I will show you the example below:

```
$body = '{
  "location": "eastus",
  "properties": {
    "kubernetesVersion": "1.14.6",
    "dnsPrefix": "xxxxx",
    "agentPoolProfiles": [
      {
        "count": 2,
        "vmSize": "Standard_DS2_v2",
        "osDiskSizeGB": 100,
        "vnetSubnetID": "xxxxxxxx",
        "maxPods": 30,
        "osType": "Linux",
        "type": "AvailabilitySet",
        "orchestratorVersion": "1.14.6",
        "name": "agentpool"
      }
    ],
    "addonProfiles": {
      "httpapplicationrouting": {
        "enabled": false,
        "config": {}
      },
      "omsagent": {
        "enabled": true,
        "config": {
          "loganalyticsworkspaceresourceid": "xxxxxxxx"
        }
      }
    },
    "nodeResourceGroup": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "enableRBAC": true,
    "networkProfile": {
      "networkPlugin": "azure",
      "serviceCidr": "10.1.0.0/16",
      "dnsServiceIP": "10.1.0.10",
      "dockerBridgeCidr": "172.17.0.1/16",
      "loadBalancerSku": "Basic"
    }
  }
}'
$requestUri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{your_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/{your_cluster_name}?api-version=2019-08-01"
$accessToken = "xxxxxxx"
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"} -Uri $requestUri -Method PUT -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $body
```

You can change the context in the body as you need and the properties describe in the REST API.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how to use the REST API? I have a hard time understanding their documentation. It seems rather cryptic how I am supposed to specify which nodepools and such.

Comment: @Shadesfear I update the answer to add the PowerShell script as you wish. And if it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Shadesfear Any update for your current situation? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I just got around to trying it out, I keep getting this error: 
[Error Message] The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.  I tried out some different options in the $body, but it's still the same

Comment: @Shadesfear You can get the property of your AKS cluster, and then change the format as the answer shows.

Comment: Yes I ran this command az aks show -n <name> --resource-group <rgname>. And tried to use that. But still got 400

Comment: @Shadesfear I recommend you get the property through the REST API [Managed Clusters - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/get).

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. Thanks for all the help